# Email validation through jquery unobtrusive

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validate

I want to `validate` my `email address` through jquery `unobtrusive validation`. Like to make

any field required , `data-val-required` attribute is added in the field. So same for email

validation which attribute i can use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use:

```
<input type="email" ... />
```

Of course you need to add the jQuery validation plugin, but I guess you did that already or else the `data-val-required` won't work either.

Comment: @symcbean. jQuery know to treat it with HTML 4 as well if I'm not wrong.

Comment: Maybe some jQuery plugin but not jQuery

Comment: @Esailija. Yep, looked at [the source code](http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.9/jquery.validate.js). jQuery plugin handle the type="email".

Comment: @gdoron I see, I didn't see that mentioned in the question at all. I'll add the tag..